# How to open a link in an iframe of another HTML page?

Tags: html, iframe

How to open a link in an Iframe to another page?

*Example:*
I have `Page1.html`, it contains a link.
I have `Page2.html`, which contains an iframe.

If I click on the link on `Page1.html`, its target should be opened in the iframe of `Page2.html`.

Comment: What progress did you make?

Comment: I'm able to open a page in a current Iframe not **Iframe** of another page..@CMate

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh)

Comment: Also I suggest don't use FULL CAPITAL nick. It looks as an agressive behavior, and you want to get answers from us.

Comment: You can do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/2040655).

Answer (score -1):

I think it does not work in HTML5 because the "name" attribute is no longer supported which is the attribute used in HTML4.  I notice that Opera still supports the name attribute in iframe but FireFox does not.

regards, M